# How to connect 2 shapes with straight lines (like a diagram editor)

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I have two rects and I need to draw a set of lines to connect them. Only straight lines are allowed (no diagonal).

Initially I've made a grid and I've used A* path finding algorithm to find a way to connect two points located at the edges of my figures.

It works but it seems to be a little overkill; in fact I can avoid obstacles check (the rect of the objects) by assuming it can only connect nearest (and always visible) edges.
So anyone can suggest to me a simpler algorithm to do it?